# MongoDb fetch document subset using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB document structure like this:

```
 [
   {
      "locale":"en",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "locale":"ru",
      "translations":[
         {
            "name":"translation1",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"ruValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"ruValue"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and I need to get the translation with name `translation1` for locale `en`.
The expected result I want is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e845ba1005e625a6237d2e0"),
    "translations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "translation1",
            "value" : "enValue"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know how to do this with pure mongo, it should be like this:

```
db.translations.find({"locale" : "en"}, 
                     { translations: { $elemMatch: { name: "translation1" } } } )
```

Here is the proof https://gyazo.com/fb9b1a505a898c7137ece5304d715171

but I can't make it work with PHP. I tried code like:

```
$collection = $this->database->{$group};
$collection->find(
    [
        'locale' => 'en', 
        'translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']
    ]
);
```

And Im getting all translations for `en` instead of only `tranlsation1` as a result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e845ba1005e625a6237d2e0"),
    "locale" : "en",
    "translations" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "translation1",
            "value" : "enValue"
        },
         {
            "name":"translation2",
            "value":"enValue"
         },
         {
            "name":"translation3",
            "value":"enValue"
         }
    ]
}
```

I tried as:

```
$collection = $this->database->{$group};
$collection->find(
    ['locale' => 'en'],
    [
        'translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']
    ]
);
```

also result is the same as above.

Tried like:

```
$collection = $this->database->{$group};
$collection->find(
    [
        'locale' => 'en',
        [
            'translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']
        ]
    ]
);
```

result is `null`

As a workaround, for now, I filter result on PHP side, but it extra work

Comment: I wonder if this is some strangeness with how the PHP driver encodes the projection.  Test the equivalent database command: `$this->$database->command(['find'=>'CollectionName','filter'=>['locale' => 'en'],'projection'=>['translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']]]])`

Comment: yeah it works, create the answer and I'll accept it, Thank you!

Comment: I'm think you should open a bug report against that driver.  If the command works but the the `find` function doesn't, it isn't handling something right.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the driver.

This database command should be equivalent to the `find` you were running, but the command works as expected while the find does not.

```
$this->$database->command([
         'find'=>'CollectionName',
         'filter'=>['locale' => 'en'],
         'projection'=>['translations' => ['$elemMatch' => ['name' => 'translation1']]]
])
```